# How do you override new function and make it backwards compatible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, inheritance, overriding

I want to override the `setTintColor:` function for my `UIView` subclass. There's no problem doing this in iOS 7 since that function was introduced starting at that version. However, I couldn't figure out how to make this function backwards compatible with iOS 6. The following will crash.

```
- (void)setTintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor
{
    if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(setTintColor:)]) {
        // Crashes here with "unrecognized selector" in iOS 6, probably because 
        // defining setTintColor: makes respondsToSelector: return YES for all
        // objects in the hiearchy regardless of whether it is defined at its
        // level.
        [super setTintColor:tintColor];
    }
    self.label.textColor = tintColor;
    self.dividerLeft.backgroundColor = tintColor;
    self.dividerRight.backgroundColor = tintColor;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the condition to this

```
if ([UIView instancesRespondToSelector:(setTintColor:)])
```

The reason your code isnt working is because `super` is just a special version of `self` and since your subclass responds to `setTintColor:` it will return YES.